# getSource() - What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jbutton

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Just making a simple program to test concepts for a game, and I'm trying to have three buttons when clicked have three different outputs. But, for button one, two, and three, I get an error saying that they cannot be resolved to a variable. I don't know what to do. What am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 

public class CodeTestingGround extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    new CodeTestingGround();

}

public CodeTestingGround() {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    JFrame frameone = new JFrame();
    frameone.setLayout(null);

    frameone.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameone.setLocation(screenSize.width / 3, screenSize.height / 3);

    JButton buttonone = new JButton("Click here to download viruses!");
    JButton buttontwo = new JButton("Click here to get scammed!");
    JButton buttonthree = new JButton("Click here to get hacked!");
    buttonone.setBounds(10, 10, 260, 30);
    buttontwo.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
    buttonthree.setBounds(10, 90, 260, 30);
    buttonone.addActionListener(this);
    buttontwo.addActionListener(this);
    buttonthree.addActionListener(this);
    frameone.add(buttonone);
    frameone.add(buttontwo);
    frameone.add(buttonthree);
    frameone.pack();
    frameone.setVisible(true);
    frameone.setSize(300, 400);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object control = event.getSource();
    if (control == buttonone) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viruses sucessfully downloaded!", "Important Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (control == buttontwo) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE WON A MILLION DOLLARS!!! Enter you credit card information to claim your prize.", "YOU ARE WIN", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (control == buttonthree) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have been haxored", "get hacked", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }



}

}
```

Comment: Those buttons are awfully pessimistic.  Can't you add a `new JButton("Click here to have all your programs work perfectly the first time and have unicorns show up at your doorstep");`???

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: `ActionEvent` and `JButton` also supports the concept of `actionCommand` property.  Unless otherwise specified, the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` will return the text of the button, you can change this by using the `JButton#setActionCommand` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `buttons` aren't in lexical scope. Make them fields, like

```
private JButton buttonone = new JButton("Click here to download viruses!");
private JButton buttontwo = new JButton("Click here to get scammed!");
private JButton buttonthree = new JButton("Click here to get hacked!");
```

And remove the declaration and initialization from your `CodeTestingGround` constructor. Something like (or just remove the three lines)

```
// JButton buttonone = new JButton("Click here to download viruses!");
// JButton buttontwo = new JButton("Click here to get scammed!");
// JButton buttonthree = new JButton("Click here to get hacked!");
buttonone.setBounds(10, 10, 260, 30);
buttontwo.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
buttonthree.setBounds(10, 90, 260, 30);
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`ActionEvent` and `JButton` also supports the concept of `actionCommand` property.  Unless otherwise specified, the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` will return the text of the button, you can change this by using the `JButton#setActionCommand` method

```
JButton buttonone = new JButton("Click here to download viruses!");
buttonone.setActionCommand("bad");
JButton buttontwo = new JButton("Click here to get scammed!");
buttonone.setActionCommand("ugly");
JButton buttonthree = new JButton("Click here to get hacked!");
buttonone.setActionCommand("hacked");
```

And then you would use the `actionCommand` property of the `ActionEvent`...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String cmd = event.getActionCommand();
    if ("bad".equals(cmd)) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viruses sucessfully downloaded!", "Important Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if ("ugly".equals(cmd)) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE WON A MILLION DOLLARS!!! Enter you credit card information to claim your prize.", "YOU ARE WIN", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if ("hacked".equals(cmd)) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have been haxored", "get hacked", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JButtons are defined in `CodeTestingGround()`, meaning they can't be accessed outside of that method. When you try to access them from actionPerformed the JButtons are out of scope.

You can fix this by simply moving the declarations:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 

public class CodeTestingGround extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//Declarations go here instead
JButton buttonone;
JButton buttontwo;
JButton buttonthree;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException 
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    new CodeTestingGround();

}

public CodeTestingGround() {

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    JFrame frameone = new JFrame();
    frameone.setLayout(null);

    frameone.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frameone.setLocation(screenSize.width / 3, screenSize.height / 3);

    buttonone = new JButton("Click here to download viruses!");
    buttontwo = new JButton("Click here to get scammed!");
    buttonthree = new JButton("Click here to get hacked!");
    buttonone.setBounds(10, 10, 260, 30);
    buttontwo.setBounds(10, 50, 260, 30);
    buttonthree.setBounds(10, 90, 260, 30);
    buttonone.addActionListener(this);
    buttontwo.addActionListener(this);
    buttonthree.addActionListener(this);
    frameone.add(buttonone);
    frameone.add(buttontwo);
    frameone.add(buttonthree);
    frameone.pack();
    frameone.setVisible(true);
    frameone.setSize(300, 400);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object control = event.getSource();
    if (control == buttonone) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viruses sucessfully downloaded!", "Important Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (control == buttontwo) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU HAVE WON A MILLION DOLLARS!!! Enter you credit card information to claim your prize.", "YOU ARE WIN", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (control == buttonthree) { // error right here
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have been haxored", "get hacked", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
}
```